# How to specify knot locations in BSplines() function of statsmodels.gam?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels, spline

The [documentation of BSplines](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.gam.smooth_basis.BSplines.html) mentions a "knot_kwds" argument.

Suppose I want to develop Bsplines for a predictor X. Also, I want to specify the locations of the knots for the splines. How to do this using the Bsplines function? Precisely, what is the syntax for specifying the knots?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your question? The documentation explains how to use it on the page you linked.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Suppose I want to develop Bsplines for a predictor X. Also, I want to specify the locations of the knots for the splines. How to do this using the Bsplines function? Precisely, what is the syntax for specifying the knots?

Comment: The cited docs are pretty explicit about how to define the knots?  What is your problem?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I got the detailed answer [here](https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/10d797a2f185a1b29027d8afbde75d33).